# Visual Studio Extension: Build error VSSDK1043: "There was a prblem finding the extension with a VSIX identifier..."

Tags: visual-studio, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-package

I am trying to debug my extensions and suddenly I cannot build it anymore.

> Error 1   There was a problem finding the extension with a VSIX
>   identifier of "1cdefdc6-1f5e-4027-9bb7-773248c65070". Illegal
>   characters in path.

I have rolled back all changes I made and still the error occurs. I don't think that I have changed any configuration.

This is not a dupliacte of: [VSIX package build failed without showing the reason (Visual Studio bug)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747387/vsix-package-build-failed-without-showing-the-reason-visual-studio-bug) I have already tried those suggestions.

If I disabled

> Deploy VSIX content to experimental instance for debugging

it compiles, but I cannot debug it.

Changing the Product ID also works, but this means, that it can no longer update the existing product.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error message (this is how i ended up hear) and then after changing the name i got the following error

`VSIX development error VSSDK1040: There was a problem enabling the extension with a VSIX`

Stumbled on the solution found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/98dda5fc-1b07-474a-a73e-4e1a4cc23ab8/vsix-development-error-vssdk1040-there-was-a-problem-enabling-the-extension-with-a-vsix-identifier?forum=vsx)

What he did was delete this folder `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio`

So i did that, am going to have to re-install a handful of extensions now as i am getting errors from them but it did correct my issue.

maybe you can dig a little deeper into the folder to find just the needed items to remove or do what i did and just nuke the folder and pick up the pieces

**EDIT:** from comments you may be able to get away with just removing anything under 'C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio' with the EXP extension

Comment: I can't reproduce the error anymore, so I can't verify you solution. But thanks for sharing anyway, good to know :)

Comment: @FlorianGerhardt, expected that to be the case being that you posted this a year ago but figured putting the answer here may help somone

Comment: Just delete the folders in `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio` that end with `Exp`. This is an issue related to the launching of Experimental version of Visual Studio when you debug your extensions. No need to delete more.

Comment: @SverrirSigmundarson, can you edit my response or elaborate and i will edit my answer